# Problem related to IPython.display import video for displaying video

Tags: python, video, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I am new to OpenCV, and have this code for displaying the video in .avi format, but in the output the video is displaying, but not playing. I am working on UCF101 dataset.

from IPython.display import Video

```
# List of .avi files
avi_files = ['UCF101/v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g01_c01.avi',<br>
             'UCF101/v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g01_c02.avi',<br>
             'UCF101/v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g01_c03.avi',<br>
             'UCF101/v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g01_c04.avi',<br>
             'UCF101/v_ApplyEyeMakeup_g01_c05.avi']<br>

# Display the first video in the list
Video(avi_files[1],embed=True)


type(Video(avi_files[1],embed=True))
IPython.core.display.Video
```

I have tried embed and different:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import Video
```

But it is not working.